# photoelectric effect when the plate is moving

Tags: special-relativity, photoelectric-effect

Consider a plate that is moving away from the light source with respect to the ground and the frequency of the light is equal to the threshold frequency. Now if we observe the same experiment from a frame where the plate is not moving in such a frame the frequency of the light will decrease and the work function of the plate will increase hence there should be no electron emitted in such a frame. but we know that  electron will emitted in every frame, so please tell me where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Your set up that leads to an apparent contradiction is unclear. If the emitter or plate are moving, you need to be clear which is doing what relative to a frame of your choosing.